# unable to build on macOS

Tags: git, macos, go, git-pull

So I'm trying to pull down my fork and I keep getting this:

```
$ go get github.com/foobar/gostuff.git
# github.com/foobar/gostuff.git/vendor/github.com/dswarbrick/smart/ioctl
src/github.com/foobar/gostuff.git/vendor/github.com/dswarbrick/smart/ioctl/ioctl.go:67:30: undefined: unix.SYS_IOCTL
```

Other people seem to be able to pull this down just fine on their macs. I've tried to:

- Reinstall go
- run `go get -u golang.org/x/sys/unix`

Nothing works and I am at a loss, I'm pretty new to Go so maybe I'm missing something, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears you're using vendored dependencies, so `go get` is never going to update them. Start by using go modules.

Comment: Drop `.git` from the end when you're "go get'ting" it. Or use "Go Modules".

Answer (score 2):

running this solved my problem: export GOARCH=amd64; export GOOS=linux; go build